# Knowing when a custom Event is Added or Removed?

Tags: javascript, custom-events

I have a Javascript class, `Engine`, that will create new events (eg `const event = new Event('build');`) and then dispatch them at the appropriate time, when Intervals elapse or it catches certain events, using `elem.dispatchEvent(event);`

I have other classes eg `MyButton` that will listen for the events eg `elem.addEventListener('build', myListener, false);`. NOTE: `MyButton` is not just a button - it's a class that adds a button, listens to it and other events, and does various tasks both in response to a click and through other ways.

Main question: is there a way for the `Engine` class to intercept, catch or otherwise know when its event is added and removed, so that it can start and stop the Intervals etc. as needed? Basically an `onAddEventListener` event, or a way to achieve the same effect. I can see that it could eg have functions for adding the event listeners:

```
AddIntervalListener(listener) {
    // check if the Interval is started, and if not then start it
    if (this.waitingIntervalId == null)
        this.waitingIntervalId = setInterval(catchIntervalAndFireEvent, 500);
    // add the event for the caller
    elem.addEventListener('build', listener, false);
}
```

But is there a better way so that `MyButton` can call `addEventListener()` directly, and `Engine` knows and can start the Interval as needed?

Minor question: `Engine` is not associated with a particular element in the page. Is there a best practice choice for which element in the page `Engine` should use to fire the events, ie the `elem` in `elem.addEventListener()`? eg `window` or `document` or something else? [Why do custom events need to be dispatched to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698894/why-do-custom-events-need-to-be-dispatched-to-an-object) says I have to but it doesn't address which to use. Or should I take its implied advice, and make my own event/listener system?

Comment: basically you want an event something like `onAddEventListener`. There's no such thing as I'm aware

Comment: Yep, that's about right, that's what I'm hoping for, or a way to achieve the same effect. I'm going to add your point to my question, as it's a good way of making it clear, thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer several times, with growing understanding of your needs. Please check again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using your own button implementations, simply implement a `addEventListener()` method there which raises a `customEventAdded` event whenever it is called:

Here's an example:

```js
class Engine {
  constructor() {
    this.handleCustomEventAdded = this.handleCustomEventAdded.bind(this); // do this if you need to access the engine instance inside the listener
    document.addEventListener('customEventAdded', this.handleCustomEventAdded);
  }
  handleCustomEventAdded(event) {
    console.log(`Engine learned: a ${event.detail.element.tagName} element was added a listener for ${event.detail.name}`)
  }
}

class MyButton extends HTMLButtonElement {
  addEventListener(event, handler, capture) {
    // pass the method call to HTMLButtonElement.prototype.addEventListener
    super.addEventListener(event, handler, capture);
    console.log(`Eventlistener for ${event} added`);
    switch (event) {
      case 'build':
        let evt = new CustomEvent(
          'customEventAdded', {
            bubbles: true,
            detail: {
              name: event,
              element: this
            }
          }
        );
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
        break;
      default: // noop
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('my-button', MyButton, {
  extends: 'button'
});

new Engine();

document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('build', function(event) {
  // whatever
})
```

```html
<button is="my-button" id="foo">My derived button</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, Connexo. It's very interesting. I mean, at first glance it's the opposite of what I was looking for (since it has the Button sending a custom event, instead of Engine) but in point of fact it does do a key part of what I need, which is to let the Engine know when an eventListener is added. The Engine could then store that information and use it to send out its events in turn. So yes, that would work, many many thanks.

Comment: Question: Could MyButton extend window, so that it worked when you added a listener to window?

Comment: Either way, it's not what I was after but I think it would work so I'm going to see if there are any other replies that are a closer fit to my question, and if not then I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: To my knowledge, you can only extend *elements*. What you can do is `<body is="my-body">`, or `<html is="my-root">` to have a common place to which all the events eventually bubble up.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not going to fly... it's not my web page so I can't do that.

Comment: Well any wrapper element around all of your application can do this job.

Comment: could you explain that last?

Comment: As for the wrapper element - I suggested using the body or the root element not because they are what they are, but because all bubbling event eventually notify these elements. If you cannot control these, but only have partial control over the HTML, a `<div is="my-app-root">` around all of the HTML controlled by you can do the same job.

Comment: OK. I could add a wrapper element (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938248/insert-a-div-element-as-parent), though I don't know if that will affect the page's function. I guess I would have to test, and hope the page owner doesn't change it later. Thanks again.

Comment: I've given this a lot of thought @connexo. I'm very grateful for your answer but I don't believe it is an answer to my question, as I have a load of limitations on what I can do, and the method you suggest and your (very reasonable) assumptions of things that I did not specify (but also did not explicitly rule out) will quite probably break those limitations. Still it IS an answer to someone's question, and I'm voting it up on that basis but NOT accepting it as the answer. (I'd guess this is why the downvote, but I don't know for sure)

Comment: To match that, I will post my much simpler (and less great) solution, which is an alternative, and I will not accept THAT as the answer either. That way, both possible solutions are there for other people in the future, and they can use whichever seems best for them..

Comment: Honestly I don't see where your problem is. The solution in the answer neither needs a wrapper element under your control (`Engine` is just using `document` to place its listener there) nor does it require you to tie `Engine` to an element.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding @connexo, for this to work `myButton` has to extend HTMLButtonElement or similar, and it has to actually be on the HTML page as part of the document. It is currently not an element on the page, and not an HTMLButtonElement (or anything else except a class). I tried creating the class on its own, not in the document, and it did not work; I tried programmatically adding a button to the page and could not, because I could not work out how to make it include 'is="my-button"' (I'll admit, not a lot of time spent on that last one as it doesn't really help me).

Comment: Currently myButton is just a management class that does various things, including adding and removing <div> buttons (which are not always present), running Intervals, and catching various events (including onScroll, onClick, onLoad, etc). I add listeners to the document and to the <div> as needed. I had thought to centralise some of the events (onScroll and onLoad) and Intervals in Engine, and have it fire them out using events, and then have myButton subscribe as needed. Your system, unless I have it wrong, needs myButton to be an element on the page when it's not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple, inelegant solution compared to @connexo's. Still, it does what I needed. Each method has different benefits and disadvantages. I had hoped for something in between, for example where Engine's Subscriber management instead uses events, or perhaps something else; if you have such a solution, please do put it here.

```
class Engine {
    
    intervalTime = 200;
    intervalId = null;
    
    subscribers = [];

    constructor(intervalTime) {
        if (intervalTime!==undefined)
        {   // parameter not omitted in call
            this.intervalTime = intervalTime;
        }

        this.initialise();
    }

    initialise() {
        window.addEventListener("load", this.windowLoadEvent.bind(this));
        this.intervalId = setInterval(this.doInterval.bind(this), this.intervalTime);
    }
    
    // =======================
    
    addSubscriber(subscriber) {
        // note: does not check if subscriber already subscribed
        // could check here if this is the first subscriber and only then start Interval/listening to event
        this.subscribers.push(subscriber);
    }
    
    removeSubscriber(subscriber) {
        // could check here if this is the last subscriber and stop any Interval/listening to event
        this.subscribers = this.subscribers.filter(val => val !== subscriber);
    }

    // =======================
    
    windowLoadEvent() {
        // do stuff
        this.doEvent();
    }
    
    // =======================

    doInterval() {
        for (let i=0; i<this.subscribers.length; i++)
            this.subscribers[i].doRegularInterval();
    }

    doEvent(myVariable) {
        for (let i=0; i<this.subscribers.length; i++)
            this.subscribers[i].doEvent(myVariable);
    }
    
}

class ButtonManager {

    myEngine = null;

    constructor(myEngine) {
        this.myEngine = myEngine;

        this.initialise();
    }


    initialise() {
        myEngine.addSubscriber(this);
    }
    
    // =======================
    
    doInterval() {
        // do stuff
    }
    
    doURLChanged(myVariable) {
        // do stuff
    }
}


let theEngine = new Engine();
let theButton = new ButtonManager(theEngine);
```